# Setup SSH to Android device

Tags: ssh, package-management, keyboard

Sorry for cross-posting (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239535/endless-updates-on-every-boot ) but trying to ask wider to get an answer.

How do I go about setting up a SSH connection to a remote device (a treadmill running Android 4.4.4 Ubuntu kernel 3.0.36+)? The remote device is connected via WiFi to the internet and I can run packages through the file manager (saved on USB thumb drive). The system seems very limited, both Google play and Opera don't work properly.

Manufacturer gone out of business so no support from that side. No other inputs (ethernet, RS232 etc.) At this stage USB is the only possible entry point. Guessing I need to load SSH client package, possibly bluetooth keyboard may be another entry point. Any suggestions, please.

Comment: If the remote device runs an SSH server, you just run an SSH client on your local device. Most (all?) Linux distributions and probably also MacOS have an SSH client built-in, and there are several solutions for Windows and other platforms. However, you need to know an account and password on the remote device, or have a private SSH key whose public key is installed on the it.

Comment: I tried loading SSH (via a package on USB) but I think I was blocked by account and password details. Can you provide exact details how I go about this using only file manager?

Comment: you have to add an ssh**d** server on android. I manage to found one for a fire kindle, I expected some exists for plain android as well. I defined user/passwd within the application, and can ssh when app is running.

Comment: The only way I know for installing something on Android is with the Google play store. Here is one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.galexander.sshd&hl=en_US&gl=US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish, but Termux is great as a client as well as ssh server. After the install you just need to install the openssh package with apt/pkg install openssh. (They use a wrapper so it doesn't matter if you use apt or pkg)

They even have a wiki about it https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access

A nice addition (if you want to use it as a ssh-server) is tmate. With that you don't need any kind of port-porwarding ;)

**EDIT:** Be sure to download Termux from F-Droid tho, as the GooglePlay version is severly outdated

Comment: Thanks, however, Termux seems to only support Android 5.

I think the problem is that the software engineers cut costs by installing a cheap CPU with minimal memory and a stripped-down version of Android 4.4.4. Without detailed error logs, I am unable to identify what the problems are and the keyboard layout occasionally reverts to Chinese.

I think ultimately I may have to install a mini CPU such as a Rasberry Pie or tablet and control the treadmill's inputs/outputs (speed and height) through a USB. But that is for later :-)  For now, I need to control Android's input and output

Answer (score 0):

Spent most of the day trying to get this to work. The problem is the minimalistic kernel and lack of pre-loaded apps especially the lack of support for Google apps. I deleted all apps that were flagged as "downloaded". This fixed the "Android is updating" boot message. I also stopped WiFi as I suspect it was sending usage statistics to a non-existing website. I turned off Bluetooth and location support. Finally, I went through all the developer options and turned force GPU, etc one at a time (reboot & next...). I added Google keyboard input but whilst it fixed the Chinese characters I got the boot updating message again.

The software is now usable for the main functionality with much less lag. Long term I probably have to control the treadmill through a new standard tablet. With the tweaks I can now watch videos while running (off the USB not live) should I choose. Modzilla answered the initial question and asked what the real intent was, hence I flagged their answer as correct.